# How to declare and use variables in SQL

Tags: sql, variables

This is my query - please help me with how to use variable in the below query [Variable marked with Bold]

```
create view cost_sheetNO (cost_No, line_No, EC, ATE, SP, E_GMValue, E_GMperc)
as  
    select 
        Vcost_sheet_line.[Cost Sheet No_], 
        Vsales_line.[Costsheet No_], 
        Vcost_sheet_line.[Landing Price],
        (select SUM(Vcost_sheet_line.[Landing Price]) 
         from Vcost_sheet_line 
         where Vsales_line.[Costsheet No_] = Vcost_sheet_line.[Cost Sheet No_]),
        Vcost_sheet_line.[List Price] * Vcost_sheet_line.[Special Vendor Discount _],
        (select declare @a decimal = sales_headerSO.OV - sales_headerSO.EC 
         from sales_headerSO), 
        (select @a - sales_headerSO.EC 
         from sales_headerSO)
    from 
        Vcost_sheet_line, Vsales_line 
    where 
        Vsales_line.[Costsheet No_] = Vcost_sheet_line.[Cost Sheet No_]
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't use variables in a view. Have you tried a stored procedure?

Comment: Also can't `DECLARE` a variable as part of a `SELECT` statement. A `DECLARE` need to be a separate statement to a `SELECT` . I.e. `DECLARE @a int; SET @a = 1; SELECT @a;` I've removed the RDBMS tags from your post as well; SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products. Please update your post and tag **only** the correct RDBMS.

Comment: SQL is a standard for a query language and does not have "variables". Which database product (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, ...) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

A view doesn't have parameters, but you could implement a tabular function (your code looks like SQL Server) to get the same result depending on a parameter.

```
create function cost_sheetNO (@a decimal) 
returns table
return (
  select Vcost_sheet_line.[Cost Sheet No_], Vsales_line.[Costsheet No_], Vcost_sheet_line.[Landing Price], 
         (select SUM(Vcost_sheet_line.[Landing Price]) 
          from Vcost_sheet_line 
          where Vsales_line.[Costsheet No_] = Vcost_sheet_line.[Cost Sheet No_]), 
         Vcost_sheet_line.[List Price]*Vcost_sheet_line.[Special Vendor Discount _], 
         (select @a - sales_headerSO.EC from sales_headerSO)       
          from Vcost_sheet_line, Vsales_line       
          where Vsales_line.[Costsheet No_] = Vcost_sheet_line.[Cost Sheet No_] 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column INTO @variable
```

if I understand your problem correctly